Data lineage - Remove the all comments from [VIEW_DEFINITION] in Azure SQL DW
I need to list the columns and tables that are used in the creation of the view [dimension].[v_dim_customer] .
To do this, I query the value of the column [VIEW_DEFINITION] which contains the SQL query for creating the view.
SELECT 
v.TABLE_SCHEMA,v.TABLE_NAME, v.VIEW_DEFINITION

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS v 
ON c.TABLE_NAME = v.TABLE_NAME
and c.TABLE_SCHEMA = v.TABLE_SCHEMA
WHERE v.table_name = 'dimension'
AND c.table_schema = 'v_dim_customer' 




TABLE_SCHEMA
TABLE_NAME
VIEW_DEFINITION




dimension
v_dim_customer
CREATE VIEW [dimension].[v_dim_customer] AS    SELECT        -- primary key        KNA1.fk_MANDT_KUNNR AS sk_customer,         -- attributes        KNA1.[NAME1_nom],         --  KNA1.[DEAR1_concurrents],         -- KNA1.[DEAR2_responsable_adv],         ----- /flag client interne/externe/-----        flag_ext_int.externe_interne_code,         /* flag client interne/externe niveau 2 (détaillé : intra groupe / intra société / externe)*/        flag_ext_int.externe_interne_level_2_code,         --   date pour delta        -- CY.max_slt_datetime        -- add --18/12/2023    FROM         [e3p].[KNA1] KNA1    LEFT OUTER JOIN         [e3p].T005T T005T ON KNA1.[fk_MANDT_LAND1] = T005T.[fk_MANDT_LAND1]                          AND T005T.[bk_SPRAS_code_langue] = N'F' -- français     LEFT OUTER JOIN          [e3p].T016T ON KNA1.[fk_MANDT_BRSCH] = T016T.[fk_MANDT_BRSCH]          -- AND KNA1.[SPRAS_code_langue] = T016T.[bk_SPRAS_code_langue]                     AND T016T.[bk_SPRAS_code_langue] = N'F' -- français     -- modif ska 03/12 : ajout  delai moyen de paiement, credit autorisé et recommendé     -- LEFT OUTER JOIN [e3p].[v_KNKK_fr_compute] as KNKK ON KNA1.bk_MANDT_mandant = KNKK.bk_MANDT_mandant     -- AND KNA1.bk_KUNNR_client = KNKK.bk_KUNNR_client



BUT the script contains comments that I want to exclude from my analysis.
for example the column <-- KNA1.[DEAR1_concurrents]> is commented so it is not part of the columns that I need to list.
It is possible to exclude all comments but not manually because I have several other SQL queries
I tried to use regular expressions but it does not work because they are not supported in Azure SQL DW
